# Sitecore powershell - Get the count of media folders and media items for each of the medial folders inside media library

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to get the count of all the media items and folders inside any media folder in media library. Then export the data to csv
I am planning to write a script using SPE.
Please help me on the same

For Example

- A(Media Folder)

  - A1 (Media Item)
  - A2 (Media Item)
  - A3 (Media folder)

    - A31 (Media Item)
    - A32 (Media Item)
- B(Media Folder)

  - B1 (Media Item)
  - B2 (Media folder)

    - B21 (Media Item)
    - B22 (Media Item)
  - B3 (Media folder)

    - B31 (Media Item)
    - B32 (Media Item)

I need to get final result as

[image]

Please help me on the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prepared the powershell script for you. Try it:

```
$mediaLibriary = Get-Item "/sitecore/media library"
$mediafoldersTemplates = "Media folder", "Node"

$root = $mediaLibriary.Children
$table = @()

foreach($rItem in $root){
    if($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $rItem.TemplateName){
        $table += ProcessChildren -item $rItem
    }
}

$table  | Format-Table -AutoSize

function ProcessChildren($item)
{
    $contOfFolders = 0
    $contOfImages = 0

    $children = $item.Children

    $result = @()
    $tempTable = @()
    foreach($chItem in $children){
        if($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $chItem.TemplateName)
        {
            $contOfFolders++
            $tempTable += ProcessChildren -item $chItem
        }else{
            $contOfImages++
        }
    }


    $objAverage = New-Object System.Object
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $item.Name
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name FolderCount -Value $contOfFolders
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name ItemCount -Value $contOfImages

    $result += $objAverage
    $result += $tempTable

    return $result
}
```

> You can upgrade the `mediafoldersTemplates` variable in the script with a template names that you consider are folder's templates.

Comment: Hi,
The code you provided is working as expected.
Thanks

Comment: As a matter of preference, I like to create new objects using the syntax `$average = [pscustomobject]@{"Name"=$item.Name}`. SPE depends on PowerShell 3+ which is when that syntax became available. Also, I would move the function to the top of the script.

Comment: Yes Michael, i moved the function to top of script and then only it worked.
Also will take care of creating new objects using the provided syntax

Comment: @MichaelWest Thanks guys for your comments. I am not really familiar with PowerShell. Any saggestions for improving will be appreciated.

Comment: First, check out the #module-spe channel on the Sitecore Slack Chat. Many PowerShell users hang out there. Second, the module has a companion book https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/. Third, the book _[Professional Sitecore 8 Development](https://www.apress.com/br/book/9781484222911)_ has a chapter (10) I wrote which covers using the SPE module.